# Powershell - Search for all IP addresses except 127.0.0.1 in all files and subdirectories

Tags: regex, shell, powershell, ip

I want to search for all IP addresses except 127.0.0.1 in all files and subdirs of a given path.

I have tried:

```
function searchstr($string)
{
    ls -Recurse | Select-String $string -List | Select Path
}
```

And this allows me to search for specific ip's

```
searchstr "192.153.133.2"
```

but not all ips...

I usually do this with regular expressions in eclipse like this: 1) 
`ctrl + h` =>
[image]

But this project is so big and has so many references to ips that eclipse dies when I try to run that regular expression on it.

I want my output to look like:

```
C:\full\path\to\file.php
C:\full\path\to\ipFile.txt
```

and to exclude entries with `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try.  It may be possible to modify the regex to perform the 127.0.0.1 exclusion in the `Select-String` command but I am not sure.  I only know enough about regex to get by.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse `
| Select-String -Pattern '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' `
| ? { $_.Line -ne '127.0.0.1' } `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -Unique
```

**Update**

Give this a try.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse `
| Select-String -Pattern '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' -AllMatches `
| ? { 
    $matches = ($_.Matches | Select-Object -Unique)
    return $matches.Count -gt 1 -or $matches[0].Value -ne '127.0.0.1' 
} `
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -Unique
```

This should exclude files containing lines like the one the OP brings up in the comments:

> ip address = 127.0.0.1

But it will not exclude files with lines such as the following (the suggested fixes would exclude files with this line):

> ip address = 127.0.0.1; ip address = 8.8.8.8

Comment: It doesn't account for a line like `ip address =  127.0.0.1`.

Comment: You should use `-notlike "*127.0.0.1*"` to filter it rather than `-ne`.

Comment: or -notcontains

Comment: Yep, that update is the correct answer. Just curious, if I wanted to output the IP that the regex matched, is it stored in: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path -Unique`?

Comment: Well, the `Select-Object` command does not store anything. You have `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` objects that are being piped into the command (the result of the `Select-String` command) and then the `Path` property of the `MatchInfo` object is piped out. The `Path` property is, obviously, the file path. The `Matches` property is the property that contains the IP addresses that matched the pattern (there may be more than one match - see my last example). Take a look at the other properties `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo].GetProperties() | Select -Property Name`.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Turns out Select-Strings returns something that stores a bunch of properties about it. Check my edit on your answer, it looks pretty now :)

Answer (score 1):

try this ;)

```
 $dirroot="C:\temp\root"
 $IPregex=[regex]‘(?<Address>((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))’
 gci -Recurse $dirroot -File | foreach {$res=(Get-Content $_.fullname); if ($res -Match $IPregex -and $Matches.Address -ne "127.0.0.1"  ) {New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{IP=$IPregex.Match($res).Value; File=$_}} }
```

Comment: Just tried it on my test folder. It seems to be matching `127.0.0.1` instead of excluding it for some odd reason. Every IP in the output was `127.0.0.1`. Would have thought `-and $Matches.Address -ne "127.0.0.1"` accounted for it. Really like the output format of your answer though. That looks like exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Strange, it work on my test folder. What is your version of PowerShell? Mine is 5.1.14393.206, try to update if inferior

Comment: I'm on `Major  Minor  Build  Revision 4      0      -1     -1      ` I'll try to update